# Export rpivottable output as image

Tags: r, shiny, rpivottable

I recently started using rPivotTable to produce some impressive charts and tables. I am using rPivotTable in a Shiny application. I was wondering if it is possible to export the output of the rPivotTable(Table, Bar chart, line chart etc) as image from the web browser. In RStudio(without Shiny), it can be done as the viewer has an option for Export->Save as Image. Is there any way to save the charts and tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pivotTable is a htmlwidget, so you can use `htmlwidgets::saveWidget` to save the table in a html file and `webshot::webshot` to export it to `png` (or `pdf`).

```
library(shiny)
library(rpivotTable)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(webshot)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  rpivotTableOutput("pivotbl"),
  br(),
  downloadButton("export", "Export")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  pivotTable <- rpivotTable(
    Titanic,
    rows = "Survived",
    cols = c("Class","Sex"),
    aggregatorName = "Sum as Fraction of Columns",
    inclusions = list( Survived = list("Yes")),
    exclusions= list( Class = list( "Crew")),
    vals = "Freq",
    rendererName = "Table Barchart"
  )

  output[["pivotbl"]] <- renderRpivotTable({
    pivotTable
  })

  output[["export"]] <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      "pivotTable.png"
    },
    content = function(file){
      tmphtml <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
      saveWidget(pivotTable, file = tmphtml)
      webshot(tmphtml, file = file)
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

## EDIT

Here is a way to export only the graph, using the **dom-to-image** JavaScript library.

Download the file [dom-to-image.min.js](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image/tree/master/dist) and put it in the **www** subfolder of the app.

Here is the app:

```
library(shiny)
library(rpivotTable)

js <- "
function filter(node){
  return (node.tagName !== 'i');
}
function exportPlot(filename){
  var plot = document.getElementsByClassName('pvtRendererArea');
  domtoimage.toPng(plot[0], {filter: filter, bgcolor: 'white'})
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.download = filename;
      link.href = dataUrl;
      link.click();
    });
}
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('export', exportPlot);
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "dom-to-image.min.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  br(),
  rpivotTableOutput("pivotbl"),
  br(),
  actionButton("export", "Export")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  pivotTable <- rpivotTable(
    Titanic,
    rows = "Survived",
    cols = c("Class","Sex"),
    aggregatorName = "Sum as Fraction of Columns",
    inclusions = list( Survived = list("Yes")),
    exclusions= list( Class = list( "Crew")),
    vals = "Freq",
    rendererName = "Table Barchart"
  )

  output[["pivotbl"]] <- renderRpivotTable({
    pivotTable
  })

  observeEvent(input[["export"]], {
    session$sendCustomMessage("export", "plot.png")
  })  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6474
PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.

Comment: @SuneelKumar So did you run `webshot::install_phantomjs()`?

Comment: see my code here [link](https://gist.github.com/suneelisk/2cbfb650e366476590edf06e9a4acb2f)

Comment: 1.Click Browse button select xlsx format file. 2.in (Select One...) selectinput select Table and then click Lets Go button. after that click Download Data... button data will be download

Comment: if i select Image by clicking Download Widget only Plot should be download not entire HTML widget

Comment: @SuneelKumar Please see my edit. This app exports only the graph.

Comment: Now It's Working fine i can able to download image. Thank you Laurent for helped me out from this issue